# how to add the auto increment number after file number (file number is a attribute of a table)

Tags: php

i have a table called dispatch which contains attributes like file name, subject and so on.
what i want as output is data of file-name/auto-increment-num.
EG: MD/ICT/2018/1 and next value will be like
    MD/ICT/2018/2 and so on..

MD/ICT/2018/1 and next value will be like
    MD/ICT/2018/2 and so on..

Comment: submit some code first]

Answer (score 2):

I think there to way to make it happen or consider.

1. maybe if the year changes need also to reset count back to 1.

   - for the case need to check currect year search and count the record increment but 1 before insert the record.
2. if ever no delete function or consideration count per year just use auto_increment as basis of numbering.